# UISlider following sound volume, not working

Tags: core-audio, avaudioplayer, audio

I am having an issue in my iPhone app with sound.
I have a UISlider object that I use to adjust the sound volume.

When it appears I use code based on the following line, to set the initial value of the slider:

```
AudioSessionGetProperty ('chov',&dataSize,&volume);
```

and that works fine. Then I would like the slider to move accordingly when I activate the hardware sound volume buttons of the device.
But this part based on this kind of code:

```
AudioSessionPropertyID volumeChangeID=kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareOutputVolume;
AudioSessionAddPropertyListener(volumeChangeID,handleSoundVolume,self);
```

does not work so well.
What I can see is that the callback function:handleSoundVolume is only called when some sound is playing and not otherwise.
On the other hand the value provided by AudioSessionGetProperty is always correct independently of sound playing or not.
Why is that?

I thought AudioSessionGetProperty and AudioSessionAddPropertyListener were working "together", but it does not seem so.

Looking at the default Music app on iPod touch, it seems that what I want to do is quite possible.

Thanks for any piece of information.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the same problem, the callback did not work at all for me.

The best solution is to add an observer to the NSNotificationCenter, for property AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification.

```
NSNotificationCenter * center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(volumeChanged:)
               name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"
             object:nil];
```

and you have the method

```
- (void)volumeChanged:(NSNotification*)notification
{
     float volume = [[[notification userInfo]
                        objectForKey:@"AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter"]
                      floatValue];
}
```

by the way I recommend instead of using 'chov' you should use the constant

```
kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareOutputVolume
```